# Match MySQL Time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date, select

This seems like a simple task, and I've seen others ask the same question, but I still can't return any results from my SQL query.  I've got a date column that's set by timestamp default current.  So it reads YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS.

My SQL query is as follows:

```
select `paid` from customer_det where `office` = "Blanding" and `date`= CURDATE();
```

I return a result set when I get rid of the and date = curdate.  So I'm curious how to match the two dates.  I just need to pull results that have been inserted today, the actual time is irrelevant.

Thanks.

Comment: i meant format the date column to be the right format. I think its something like DATE_FORMAT('Y-m-d', date)

Comment: It is in the right format, it just has extra values...

Comment: Suppose two approaches, use `Date_Format` as nathan suggests, or make the criteria a range.  using `BETWEEN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the timestamp to just get the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) portion and compare:

```
SELECT `paid` FROM customer_det WHERE `office` = "Blanding" AND DATE(`date`) = CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 1):

`CURDATE()` returns YYYY-MM-DD.

Your date values are YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS, so  `date = CURDATE()` will always be false.
Because what you are doing is `'2012-11-07 21:58:47' = '2012-11-07'`, which is obviously not the same.

Instead, you could use mysql's DATE() function, like this:

```
SELECT `paid` FROM customer_det WHERE `office` = "Blanding" and DATE(date) = CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do this with [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

```
select `paid` from customer_det where `office` = "Blanding" and DATEDIFF(`date`, CURDATE()) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$curDate = date("Y-m-d");
$query = "select `paid` from customer_det where `office` = "Blanding" and `date` = $curDate";
```

It seems to me what you have listed should work.

Comment: Same as @coder1984's answer, this query only returns records for the exact same second, not for the whole day.

Comment: When I read what he wanted I read that he wanted it in that format my mistake I made my edit.

Comment: I see what you are saying now the date from the SQL query is that timestamp your answer makes more sense I will vote it up.